# WireMock gives a null response body when mocking an API call using spring boot resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

I'm facing a weird issue with Wiremock. The code below returns a null response body. Any insight will be very much appreciated.

**Stub in my test**:

```
WireMock.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("http://localhost:8080/mapper"))
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                    .withBody(asJson("ct/slotting-response/create_sample_response1.json"))
                    .withHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8")));
```

**Actual API call using spring boot resttemplate**:

```
public ResponseEntity<SampleResponse> getsampleValue(final SampleRequest request, RequestHeader requestHeader) throws SlottingException {
    try {
        log.info("Sending request[payload={}]", request);
        final HttpHeaders headers = getRequestHeader(requestHeader);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);
        final ResponseEntity<SampleResponse> response =
                restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/mapper",
                        entity, SampleResponse.class);
        log.info("Sample response {}", response); // response.getBody() gives null
        if (HttpStatus.OK.equals(response.getStatusCode())) {
            log.info("Sample allocated successfully.");
        }
        else {
            throw new SampleException("failed");
        }
        return response;
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SampleException("Failed", e);
    }
}
```

Can someone please point out any obvious mistakes you see in the Wiremock stub?

Comment: Have you tried stubbing for a relative path instead of your absolute path? `.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/mapper")))`. My best guess is that this is causing the issue, so you aren't getting a match for the stub you've created, since SpringBoot is hitting `http://localhost:8080/mapper`, and you're looking for `http://localhost:8080http://localhost:8080/mapper` as your url? I could be off base here....

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd recommend adding information on how you're starting WireMock, and more information about the specific error you're receiving.

Comment: is there any interceptor on your RestTemplate configuration? try to remove `restTemplate.setInterceptors` it will work